# Шифрование данных json

Tags: php, android, json, безопасность

Есть сервер(php), и есть клиент (приложение на android) , с клиента отправляется запрос на сервер, сервер дает ответ в формате json.

Любой, кто захочет может отправить гет запрос и увидеть данные json.

Вопрос в шифровании этих данных. Т.е нужно зашифровать их на php, и расшифровать их на клиенте.

С клиента отправляется запрос на сервер, сервер выдает зашифрованные данные в формате json, клиент расшифровывает.

Скажите пожалуйста, как это шифрование реализовать?

Comment: SSL обычный, не?

Comment: может можно использовать защищенный протокол? (https)

Comment: да был как то похожий вопрос. json можно не шифровать а вот данные в нем можно и зашифровать

Comment: @Naumov вы абсолютно правы, сейчас к этому и пришел) Как реализовать шифрование на php и дешифрование на java

Comment: @MartinezToni https://secure.php.net/manual/ru/function.openssl-encrypt.php зашифровать и расшифровать https://secure.php.net/openssl_decrypt в общем много способов и алгоритмов шифрования. Так же можно и свой алгоритм придумать(хотя не стоит велосипеды изобретать).